# PostgreSQL + Kubernetes: Role doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

I used the following yaml to create a postgres deployment in my kubernetes cluser.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: database-secret
  namespace: todo-app
data:
  # todoappdb
  db_name: dG9kb2FwcGRiCg==
  # todo_db_user
  username: dG9kb19kYl91c2VyCg==
  # password
  password: cGFzc3dvcmQK
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: database
  namespace: todo-app
  labels:
    app: database
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: database
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: database
          image: postgres:11
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: database-secret
                  key: password
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: database-secret
                  key: username
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: database-secret
                  key: db_name
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: database
  namespace: todo-app
  labels:
    app: database
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: database
  ports:
    - port: 5432
```

When I try to run psql in the pod itself using the following command.

```sh
kubectl exec -it database-5764d75d58-msf7h  -n todo-app -- psql -U todo_db_user -d todoappdb
```

I get the following error.

```sh
psql: FATAL:  role "todo_db_user" does not exist
```

Here are the logs of the pod.

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
running bootstrap script ... ok
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
syncing data to disk ... ok

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -l logfile start


WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
waiting for server to start....2022-01-15 12:46:26.009 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-01-15 12:46:26.015 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-15 12:46:25 UTC
2022-01-15 12:46:26.017 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
CREATE DATABASE


/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

waiting for server to shut down...2022-01-15 12:46:26.369 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
.2022-01-15 12:46:26.369 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2022-01-15 12:46:26.370 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 56) exited with exit code 1
2022-01-15 12:46:26.371 UTC [51] LOG:  shutting down
2022-01-15 12:46:26.376 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
 done
server stopped

PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2022-01-15 12:46:26.482 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2022-01-15 12:46:26.482 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2022-01-15 12:46:26.483 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2022-01-15 12:46:26.489 UTC [77] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-15 12:46:26 UTC
2022-01-15 12:46:26.492 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Is there something wrong with the config?

When I don't use POSTGRES_USER env var, it works using role `postgres`. Also, with the current config I tried to use psql with the `postgres` role but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have an error in your `Secret`. If you base64-decode these values:

```
data:
  # todoappdb
  db_name: dG9kb2FwcGRiCg==
  # todo_db_user
  username: dG9kb19kYl91c2VyCg==
  # password
  password: cGFzc3dvcmQK
```

You will find that they all include a terminal `\n` character:

```
$ kubectl get secret database-secret -o json > secret.json
$ jq '.data.username|@base64d' secret.json
"todo_db_user\n"
$ jq '.data.password|@base64d' secret.json
"password\n"
$ jq '.data.db_name|@base64d' secret.json
"todoappdb\n"
```

I suspect this is because you generate the values by running something
like:

```
$ echo password | base64
```

But of course, the `echo` command emits a trailing newline (`\n`).

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Use `stringData` instead of `data` in your `Secret` so you can just
   write the unencoded values:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Secret
   type: Opaque
   metadata:
     name: database-secret
   stringData:
     db_name: todoappdb
     username: todo_db_user
     password: password
   ```
2. Instruct `echo` to not emit a trailing newline:

   ```
   $ echo -n todo_db_user | base64
   ```

   (Or use something like `printf` which doesn't emit a newline by
   default).

I would opt for the first option (using `stringData`) because it's much simpler.